# Hash[[[1,2],[3,4]]] のようなHashの挙動はどのように解釈すればいいですか？

Tags: ruby

先日activesupportの`Object#instance_values`メソッドのソースコードを読んでいたら
Hashについてわからないことがあったので質問させていただきます.

```
Hash[] #=> {}
Hash[[]] #=> {}
Hash[[[]]] #=> invalid number of arguments
Hash[[[1,2],[3,4]]] #=> {1=>2, 3=>4}
```

上に挙げたこれらのコードの挙動を教えていただけますでしょうか.

下記はactivesupportの`Object#instance_values`のソースコードです.

```
def instance_values
  Hash[instance_variables.map { |name| [name[1..-1], instance_variable_get(name)] }]
end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/instance_variables.rb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

該当する部分は [Hash.[]](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/2.1.0/Hash.%5B%5D) と思われます。

> ```
> .[](key, value, ...) ⇒ Object
> .[]([ [key, value)) ⇒ Object
> .[](object) ⇒ Object
> ```
>
> Creates a new hash populated with the given objects. Equivalent to the literal { key => value, ... }. In the first form, keys and values occur in pairs, so there must be an even number of arguments. The second and third form take a single argument which is either an array of key-value pairs or an object convertible to a hash.
>
> ```
> Hash["a", 100, "b", 200]             #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
> Hash[ [ ["a", 100], ["b", 200] ] ]   #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
> Hash["a" => 100, "b" => 200]         #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>200}
> ```

要約するとハッシュのコンストラクタには、以下のようにブロックを渡せますが、

```
Hash{key1 => value1, key2 => value}
```

別の呼び出し方として、以下のバリエーションがあると受け取れます。

- `.[](key1, value1, key2, value2, ...)`
- `.[]([[key1, value1], [key2, value2], [...))`
- `.[](object)`

そこで、質問に挙げられたコードを見ていきます。

- `Hash[] #=> {}`
  これは、要素無指定なので、空のハッシュが生成されました。
- `Hash[[]] #=> {}`
  これは、`.[]([[key1, value1], [key2, value2], [...))` の指定ですが、 「key, value ペアがありません」でした。よって空のハッシュです。
- `Hash[[[]]] #=> invalid number of arguments`
  これは、`.[]([[key1, value1], [key2, value2], [...))` の指定ですが、 「key1=**無指定**, value1=**無指定**」 となり、key, value ペアを指定するための[]があるのにもかかわらず、要素の数が 0 でした。 よって "invalid number of arguments" エラーとなります。
- `Hash[[[1,2],[3,4]]] #=> {1=>2,3=>4}`
  これは、`.[]([[key1, value1], [key2, value2], [...))` の指定ですが、 `1=>2`, `3=>4` が指定され新しいハッシュが生成されました。

※ コメントにありますが、 `Hash[[[]]]` についてはバージョンによって挙動が異なるようです。

**追試:**

上記の説明で、特に、`.[]([[key1, value1], [key2, value2], [...))` の動作について、`hash.c`を追いながら追試しました。説明で抜けていたのは、 「`key1` の値だけが与えられると、 `value1=nil` とされる」ことです。以下に例を示します。

```
# tested on ruby 2.0.0p598

Hash[[]]
# => {}

Hash[[], 1]
# => {[]=>1}

Hash[[[]]]
=> invalid number of elements (0 for 1..2)

Hash[[[[]]]]
# => {[]=>nil}

Hash[[[[]]], 1]
# => {[[[]]]=>1}

Hash[[[[[]]]]]
# => {[[]]=>nil}

Hash[[[[[]], 1]]]
# => {[[]]=>1}
```

Comment: 気になったところがあったので、少し調べなおして修正し、追試しました。（鍵かっこの数でエラーになるならないということについて、説明はできましたが、バージョン間での動作の違いは不明です。）

Answer (score 5):

面白いなと思ったので調べてみました。間違っている可能性がありますので、その際にはコメントでご指摘をおねがいします。

仕様が参考になると思いますので、`Ruby 2.2.0`時点での`Hash`に関するリファレンスを貼っておきます。
http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/method/Hash/s/=5b=5d.html

これによるとHash[]とした時、引数によって内部で行われる処理が変わりそうです。

- self[other] -> Hash
- self[*key_and_value] -> Hash

ざっくりとですが [ruby/hash.c at trunk · ruby/ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c) も参考にしました。([rb_hash_s_create](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/hash.c#L566)関数が該当部分になります。)
質問にあるそれぞれのケースについて見てみます。

#### Hash[] #=> {}

`self[*key_and_value] -> Hash`の引数が0個の場合に相当し、空のHashが返ってきます。

#### Hash[[]] #=> {}

`self[*key_and_value] -> Hash`で引数が分解されますが、要素数0のため、1つ前のケースと同じ結果となります。

#### Hash[[[]]] #=> invalid number of arguments

`self[*key_and_value] -> Hash`で引数が分解されますが、要素数が1(`[]`)で奇数となるため失敗します。

尚、エラー出力箇所は 606行目あたり(変動可能性あり)の

```
 rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "invalid number of elements (%ld for 1..2)",
    RARRAY_LEN(v));
```

だと考えます。

#### Hash[[[1,2],[3,4]]] #=> {1=>2, 3=>4}

`self[*key_and_value] -> Hash`の説明の通り、KeyとValueの繰り返しとして格納される。

---

**追記**
尚、`Ruby`のバージョンによって挙動が異なる件ですが
[hash.c: raise on invalid input · 8d6add9 · ruby/ruby](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/8d6add973ebcb3b4c1efbfaf07786550a3e219af)あたりが関わっているように見えました。この修正のきっかけとなったバグは1.9.2の頃に報告されていて、2.0.0で修正されたようです。

Comment: 私も回答を書いていたのですが解釈が難しく断念しました。引数の分解（splat `*` ）に関して悩みました。ちなみに（構文解釈の違いがあるためでしょうけど） Ruby 1.9.3では `Hash[[[]]] #=> {}` でした。

Comment: Rubyのバージョンで違いがある可能性も考慮すべきでしたね。。ありがとうございます。ちなみに私も引数分解の部分でちょっともやもやしています。

Comment: splat については、幸運にも[こちらの質問](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5280/)にリサーチされた方がいます。自分でも試してみましたが、配列への splat は、 flatten() が呼び出されるだけのタイプと、引数リストに分解されるものがあって、解釈が難しいですね。

Comment: おまけです。Ruby 1.8.7でも `Hash[[[]]] #=> {}` でした。

Comment: @riocampos そしてドキュメントは一字たりとも変わらないという・・・。謎はまだ残っていそう。 Doc: [1.8.7](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/1.8.7/method/Hash/s/=5b=5d.html) / [1.9.3](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/1.9.3/method/Hash/s/=5b=5d.html) / [2.2.0](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/method/Hash/s/=5b=5d.html)

Comment: コメント参考になります。今blameしてどこで変わったか調べていますが、そもそも仕様書は変わらないんですね。。となると、この挙動はバグでしょうか。（ドキュメントはメンテされていない可能性も？）